# Создание иерархии и отображение в TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, алгоритм

Есть класс, который описывает товар:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Test
{
    public class Product
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Product> productName { get; set; }

        public string nameOfProduct { get; set; }

        public Product()
        {
            productName = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть привязка к этому коду:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="TrvView">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Product}" ItemsSource="{Binding productName}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding nameOfProduct}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Есть код, который создаёт и отображает элементы коллекции в иерархическом виде:

```
 private void Create()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            bread = new Product(){nameOfProduct = "Хлеб"};
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                breadVarieties = new Product(){nameOfProduct = "Сорт хлеба " + j.ToString()};
                bread.productName.Add(breadVarieties);
            }
            TrvView.Items.Add(bread);
        }
    }
```

На выходе получаю ожидаемый и красивый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До чего я не могу додуматься:
Как я могу реализовать код таким образом, чтобы скажем, после каждого 10го сорта хлеба создавался не  следующий корневой элемент, который расположен выше, я данные опускались ниже. Примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получается, если я сам заранее предопределяю глубину вложения (пишу ещё несколько циклов for и добавляю элементы). Как я могу сделать такое программно?

Comment: Здесь весь смысл в написании куска кода, который не имеет никакой практической ценности. А вообще вам поможет рекурсия.

Comment: Рекурсия мне в лучшем случае давала такой же результат как и выше. В худшем - зависание.

Comment: ты создаешь 10 продуктов "хлеб" с 10-ю сортами хлеба. код правильно работает. что именно ты хочешь изменить?

Comment: Значит вы наделали ошибок при написании кода.

Comment: @aepot тут я с вами не поспорю)

Comment: @Денис, напиши понятнее то, какой ответ ты хочешь. я твой вопрос не понимаю!

Comment: @aepot, ааа! теперь я понял вопрос!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WPF не работают с контролами напрямую, а вместо этого используют привязки данных. Есть шаблон проектирования MVVM, который помогает организовать WPF приложение правильно, но давайте для начала по-простому.

Назначим `DataContext` и реализуем `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _products;

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get => _products;
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // здесь будем писать код
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Для модели данных тоже реализуем INPC.

Я переименовал свойства, чтобы они выглядели понятнее и соответствовали общепринятым правилам именования в C#.

```cs
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _items = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }

    public string Name;
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

И вот такой XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Product}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Структура проекта готова. Теперь, как бы вы не меняли содержимое коллекций, как бы вы не переименовывали элементы, `TreeView` будет автоматически следить за всеми изменениями в дереве и немедленно их отображать в интерфейсе.

*Обратите внимание, у `TreeView` больше нет имени, и оно больше не нужно.*

Давайте теперь заполним дерево

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    FillProducts(Products, 10, 2, true);
}

private void FillProducts(ObservableCollection<Product> items, int count, int depth, bool isRoot)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Product product = new Product() { Name = $"{isRoot ? "Хлеб" : "Сорт хлеба"} {i + 1}" };
        items.Add(product);
        if (i == count - 1 && depth > 1)
            FillProducts(product.Items, count, depth - 1, false);
    }
}
```

Готово.

---

P.S. Можно еще чисто ради развлечения посмотреть как этот код работает визуально. Для этого добавим немного асинхронности и паузы.

```cs
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    await FillProductsAsync(Products, 10, 2, true);
}

private async Task FillProductsAsync(ObservableCollection<Product> items, int count, int depth, bool isRoot)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Product product = new Product() { Name = $"{isRoot ? "Хлеб" : "Сорт хлеба"} {i + 1}" };
        items.Add(product);
        await Task.Delay(500);
        if (i == count - 1 && depth > 1)
            FillProducts(product.Items, count, depth - 1, false);
    }
}
```

Теперь видно, как элементы добавляются в дерево один за другим визуально.

Comment: Самый ключевой момент, который помог понять мне, что я в действительности делаю не так (с помощью вашего кода): я не делал проверку на isRoot? А моя собственная реализация рекурсии ограничивалась только одним формальным параметром - int который означал нужно ли выходить из рекурсии.

Comment: @Денис с привязками данных главное разберитесь, это важнее, если хотите писать нормальный софт под WPF. И про MVVM обязательно почитайте.